# What is the probability of randomly getting a 12 word seed phrase with the same word repeated 12 times?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, math

It appears that the 12 word seed phrase **CAN** be the same word repeated 12 times.

Is it true that the probability of randomly generating that "stuttering seed phrase" would be:

= 2048 * (1/2048) <sup>12</sup>

= (1/2048) <sup>11</sup>

The logic is that there are 2048 choices at the first round and then it must pick the one chosen in the first round from then on out which has a probability of  1/2048 for the 11 remaining rounds.

Comment: Hello Ralph, please don’t answer your own question in the question post of your topic. In the question post, please focus just on asking an open question. If you want to provide your own answer, please post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct.

Remember that the last word has a checksum for the other 11, which means that not every word of the 2048 will work.

Actually, only [130 words](https://github.com/bitcoin-digest/bip39-same-words) do the trick, which means there are only 130 phrases possible in a universe of 2048^12 possible phrases, so the the probability is 130/2048^12

Comment: Wow @bordalix Thanks!  I did not even know about that.  I will update the question/answer

Comment: The correct number is 130 (not 190) and I found a better link where you can verify that.